# Error retrieving value from shared preferences

Tags: java, android

So in one activity, I am trying to put a file into shared preferences and then in another activity, I am trying to toast that string, but for some reason android is toasting the default value instead of the value I input from shared preferences.

Here is the MainActivity:

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // By default preview data is in NV21 format, if needed it must be converted
        try {
            Camera.Size previewSize = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
            int height = previewSize.height;
            int width = previewSize.width;

            ColorModelConverter converter = new ColorModelConverter(height, width);
            int[] pixels = converter.convert(data, this.colorFormat);

            int color = pickColor(pixels, height, width);
            updateColorData(color);

            storeColorInSharedPreferences(color);


            Log.i("FRAME PREVIEW", "Color updated");
        } catch (RuntimeException oops) {
            // Do nothing, exception is thrown because onPreviewFrame is called after camera is released
            Log.i("FRAME PREVIEW", "RuntimeException thrown into onPreviewFrame");
        }
    }

    public void storeColorInSharedPreferences(int color) {

        SharedPreferences sharedprefernces = getSharedPreferences("Mydata",Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedprefernces.edit();
        String first_control = String.valueOf(color);
        editor.putString("first_control", first_control);
        editor.commit();
```

And here is the second Activity:

```
public class regressionlinecalculator extends ActionBarActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_regressionlinecalculator);
    }







    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String first_control = sharedPreferences.getString("first_control", "");

    public void test(View view) {


        Toast display_final_value = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), new String(first_control), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        display_final_value.show();



    }
}
```

Test is just what happens when I click a button that I have defined in the xml file. So my question is why does android keep toasting the default value, which is "" instead of color, the value which I inputted into shared preferences in the other activity?

Comment: In the first activity there is "Mydata"  and in the second "MyData"

Answer (score 2):

> So my question is why does android keep toasting the default value,
>   which is "" instead of color, the value which I inputted into shared
>   preferences in the other activity?

it is because you are using `getApplicationContext()` for the `Toast`. Use the Activity's `Context` directly.

```
Toast display_final_value = Toast.makeText(this,first_control, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

on the other hand you have typo retrieving the SharedPreference object. Use a constant to avoid this kind of issues. Also, the initialization of it should be moved in one the callback methods. E.g. `onCreate`

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences; 
String first_control;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_regressionlinecalculator);
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Mydata",Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
    first_control = sharedPreferences.getString("first_control", "");
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other ideas for initialization besides putting in onCreate as that doesn't return anything. I am getting an error now when I run my code saying that I am trying to invoke a virtual method on a null object reference.

Answer (score 0):

In the first activity you are getting a SharedPreference from `"Mydata"`,
but in the second activity you made the 'd' uppercase, and are getting the SharedPreference for the String `"MyData"`.

Answer (score 0):

In your first method you did `getSharedPreferences("Mydata",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` and in the seconde one you did `getSharedPreferences("MyData",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

**MyData** vs **Mydata** please choose juste one correct name ;)